# Calling method inside a method in Interface c#

Tags: c#

How to call a method inside a method in same class  when using interface in c#? I got error when tried access through (object as baseclass).method

```
interface IAccount 
{ 
    string fullName{get;set;} 
    void Balance();
}

public class User : IAccount 
{ 
  public string fullName { get; set; } 
  public int balance = 10000; 
  public User(string firstName, string lastName) 
  { 
    fullName = firstName + lastName; 
  } 
  public void IAccount.Balance() 
  { 
    Console.WriteLine("Account balance-" + this.balance); 
  } 
  public void MyBalance() 
  { 
    Console.WriteLine(" My balance"); 
    IAccount.Balance(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: can we see some code?

Comment: and the code where you try to call a method inside a method?

Comment: Whats the error? please use the **edit** button in future to update your question.

Comment: remove the both `IAccount`on `public void Balance() ...` and inside `public void MyBalance()`

Comment: To make this clear: `IAccount.Balance()` would be correct if `IAccount` where a static-class - the other definition is for explicitly implementing a interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a method which is named `InternfaceName.MethodName` it is called *Explicit interface implementation*.
What it means is that that method is accessible only through a reference of the interface type.

So... How can you call to that method from within the class? Cast `this` to the interface type!

```
public void MyBalance() 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(" My balance"); 
    ((IAccount)this).Balance(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the both `IAccounton` from `public void Balance()` and inside `public void MyBalance()`

```
interface IAccount 
{ 
    string fullName{get;set;} 
    void Balance();
}

public class User : IAccount 
{ 
  public string fullName { get; set; } 
  public int balance = 10000; 
  public User(string firstName, string lastName) 
  { 
    fullName = firstName + lastName; 
  } 
  public void Balance() 
  { 
    Console.WriteLine("Account balance-" + this.balance); 
  } 
  public void MyBalance() 
  { 
    Console.WriteLine(" My balance"); 
    Balance(); 
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Account balance-10000
 My balance
Account balance-10000
```

Comment: I think you get the hint - if not look at the edit you used and the comment I gave :P